# What's the point of buying art?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

Aside from satisfying my inner completionist, is there any point in buying art in Assassin's Creed IV?

It's available for purchase from merchants pretty much right away, but it seems like a waste of money. Does buying it serve an in-game purpose or award achievements?

Comment: I am not sure as I have not picked up the newest one, but in the older games, I believe it added to the value of your estate/home.  This caused a higher amount of money to be deposited for you in every collection period.  In general, they were not worth getting early on as they are no function/high cost items.

Comment: As far as I've noticed there is't the old regular income in your home. Now if you want money you've got to go out and take it from somebody. That's the pirate way. ;-)

Comment: Grand Theft Ship. ;)

Comment: Best I can tell is that the art is included simply as a series tradition.

Comment: I don't mind it not having a function, but will the purchased items be on display somewhere? E.g. in the captain's cabin?

Comment: They are on display in your house on great Inagua, as Fogolicious answered below.

Answer (score 13):

The art you receive from Fleet missions and buying in the store shows up in your house on Great Inagua.  I am unsure if all of it does but I started to see a few in a room in the house. So I would think this is where all of it will be displayed.  Explore your house a little and you might find it.  It might also be worth mentioning that I have my house fully upgraded.

Answer (score 3):

It's only purpose is to decorate your home. It doesn't count towards 100% synchronization and there isn't an Achievement/Trophy tied to them. So besides being a decoration at your house, they are pointless.

Answer (score 0):

The art is added to your house on Great Inagua, all of the art you purchase or receive will be displayed in your home. You can also upgrade your house too.

Answer (score -2):

All that it does is decorate your home, but other than that, they're useless.